# Mercurial,  Dreamhost, and Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, dreamhost

I'm using dreamhost to host a django app, and also the static content for the app. I want to have my static content versioned together with my application code.

Because the dreamhost install of hg is version 1.0.1, to use subrepos at all, one must install ones own version of hg. I have done so.

Once that is done, it is sufficient to create a .hgsub file with the location pointing to another repo, then just add the .hgsub file.

Now, the problem I have is that I want to push to my bitbucket repository, but:

(a) I would need to upgrade my python to be able to use https; and

(b) trying ssh I get the following error:

```
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/marcintustin/oneclickcos
pushing subrepo public to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/marcintustin/public
remote: conq: repository does not exist.
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

(To confirm, I have registered my ssh key with bitbucket.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not keep editing your original question like that -- you asked one question and now you ask another (related) question. Please send us a mail at mercurial@selenic.com instead, then we can discuss.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `site` a Mercurial repository. Then add a `.hgsub` file with

```
project = project
public = public
```

and make a commit in the `site` repository. You'll see that it creates and tracks a `.hgsubstate` file with the changeset hashes of `project` and `public`. Make a local clone of `site` and the subrepositories will follow along nicely.

If that is not enough help, then my suggestion is to read the output of [`hg help subrepos`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#subrepos), the [Kick Start guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/), and the [subrepository wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository) again.

If those guides do not help you along, then come talk to us in [#mercurial on irc.freenode.net](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial) or on the [mailing list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists). Your question is not very specific and I think it is much easier to discuss this on the proper support channels.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a sensible solution. It turns out though that the problem with dreamhost is that hg was too old to support subrepos, so I had to install my own version, which now has its own problems.

Comment: You don't need any special version of Mercurial on the server to use subrepositories -- they are a client-thing.

Comment: I know, but you do need the client to support them.